# Creating RTSP streaming service for Axis camera using GStreamer GstRTSPServer

Tags: c++, gstreamer, axis, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

In the end I would like to take an RSTP stream from an Axis security camera, and then make it available for re streaming using Gstreamers GstRTSPServer object. For now though I cannot even get the example videotestsrc to play in any player.

I have been following the post found here:

[GStreamer Launch RTSP Server for ReStreaming IP Camera H264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131009/gstreamer-launch-rtsp-server-for-restreaming-ip-camera-h264)

I have gotten the example code built and running in a console, but am unable to view the stream in any players I find. EXACT code I am using found here:

https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-readme.c

Both Windows 10 computers I am using are on the same network, I can ping both directions, firewall is completely off on both computers.

I have tried VLC player, Axis Media Control SDK modified examples, and GStreamer 
using commands:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.2.3.10:8554/test latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

VLC is stating in logs that the connection was actively refused. It seems it is trying to connect to port 80? Not sure if I am reading that correctly. See VLC log below. Full log is pasted here from local machine: 
https://pastebin.com/my3kTsRV
and here from a second machine: 
https://pastebin.com/g1q47UBm

```
...Connection to server failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
Opening connection to 127.0.0.1, port 80...
...Connection to server failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
[06421494] live555 demux debug: connection error -10057
[06421494] live555 demux error: Failed to connect with rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
```

The Axis Media Control (AMC) is trowing this for an error on both the local and secondary computers:

```
503 Service Unavailable
The maximum number of clients are already connected.
```

Trying to connect using the GStreamer command I get the following error, on both local and secondary computers:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Unhandled error
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(5633): gst_rtspsrc_send (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Service Unavailable (503)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

With VLC, AMC and GStreamer I am able to pull a stream directly from a camera, so something works at least. I am also able to successfully run other GStreamer examples, without the GstRTSPServer, successfully.

Let me know if you want/need me to try anything.

Comment: Do you know ip of your cam? It can not be 127.0.0.1

Comment: At this point the camera has nothing to do with the equation. I am using a test source in place of a camera for the moment. 
It is creating the streaming service at IP 127.0.0.1, a built-in local address.

Comment: So, you've just compiled one of gst-rtsp-server examples and can't connect to it, right?

Comment: Yes, it compiles and runs, but I cannot connect.

Comment: Then try connect to rtsp://127.0.0.1/test - I don't see default port change in this example, so it shoud not use 8554 port.

Comment: do you have x264enc/videotestsrc/rtph264pay plugins installed on the sender side (gst-inspect-1.0 should tell) ?

Comment: I was wrong, according to docs https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-rtsp-server/html/GstRTSPServer.html gst-rtsp-server uses 8554 port by default. So @Prabhakar Lad could be right - you just don't have some elements installed.

Comment: RSATom, I am not sure I thought of not putting the port in, I will give that a shot. It says to put it in the console print statement so I did.

Comment: You could try do `export GST_DEBUG=3` before run, and you should see debug message from gstreamer in console.

Comment: I will check again all the plugins I am using, I did at one time, but things have changed a little in troubleshooting and I am not sure. I know I installed the "ugly" plugins pack, because x264enc was not installed by default.

Comment: And maybe you need something like `gstreamer1.0-libav` installed to get h264 support